Specify pre-commit cache directory on vscode to properly use source-control
I'm using pre-commit along with the source-control in vscode. I want to be able to specify the cache directory of pre-commit, so I defines the PRE_COMMIT_HOME environment variable in .bashrc. Everything's work well if I commit from the terminal, but if I use the version control from vscode, pre-commit keeps creating a virtual env in my home cache (which is very limited in space), not accounting for the environment variable (so I guess git is running in a separate shell).
Is it possible to specify the cache directory in the config file directly ? Or how can I define the environment variable so that the source control finds it (putting it in /etc/environment is not an option as I don't have access to write into it)

if you launch code from the terminal it should inherit that -- another solution would be to symlink the pre-commit cache to an alternative location

vscode is run from a VM (app in Citrix) and I don't have any control on how to launch it. I only have access to the settings and my home directory
